# Open files in android with in the activity

Tags: android

I have a input stream of different types of file such as 
.png,.docx,.ppt,.pdf,.ods,.txt files which i download through my webservice. I did not have a url of thes files .These files are store on cloud. How i display these files with in my android app with in the activity window....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download them, store locally (on SD card) and fire `ACTION_VIEW` intent to open file with assigned application

Comment: Yr i had done the above task which specify but problem is to open file via Intent ACTION_VIEW leaves the application & open the file in another app ,I did not like this & m working on porting one iphone app to android in which all the files open in the same window of activity not on the view of another app....

Comment: That's normal behavior. If you want to open these files in your application, you have to support for these files in your app.

Comment: How i can provide support to open files in my app because file types are not static its dynamic , the file may be of any type which user uploaded to server any other approach...

Comment: by writing code to handle certain file format? But unless you really know what you doing, you should stick to `ACTION_VIEW` as user can install any app to handle file format and you do not need to bother. That's why it is so powerful